# Unzip a tar.gz file from maven repository into build directory with gradle

Tags: copy, tar, unzip, gradle, gzip

i have a tar.gz file containing the WSDL file of a webservice and want to unzip this file into the build directory. The tar.gz file is in maven repository.
e.g. file name is my-webservice-1.10.5-wsdl.tar.gz

I tried it with a copy task and then ant.unzip, but this didn't work.

In maven i use for this the maven-dependency-plugin. Unfortunately there is no gradle equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following quick&dirty script should work; I'm sure you will manage to make it more pretty. As far as I know, there is no method to unpack tar.gz in one step.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations {
  tar
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  tar 'spice:spice-converter:1.0@tar.gz'
}

assemble << {
  // not very pretty, but fileCollection() will not work, since it performs
  // the evaluation lazily
  ant.gunzip(src: configurations.tar.files.iterator().next(), dest: 'build/tmp/ungziped.tar')
  copy {
    from tarTree('build/tmp/ungziped.tar')
    into 'build/target'
  }
}
```